# Quadratic equation formula help / simplification

Tags: quadratics

I have this quadratic equation,

$ x^{2} + \frac{10}{3}x -\frac{80}{3} = 0 $

I use the quadratic formula to solve and simplify

$-10 \pm \frac{\sqrt{100-(4)(3)(-80)}}{6}$ = $ \frac{-10 \pm \sqrt{1060}}{6}$

my book says it should simplify to

$ \frac{1}{3} ( -5 \pm \sqrt{73}) $

but i cant get this simplification can anyone show me if they can? Thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest double checking that you copied the original problem correctly.  That $\frac{1}{3} ( -5 \pm \sqrt{73})$ is not the correct answer for the quadratic you wrote down.

Comment: it seems ok, there is only a typo here for the expression $-10 \pm \frac{\sqrt{100-(4)(3)(-80)}}{6}$ but the result is correct

Comment: The  book solutions are roots of the (different) quadratic $\,x^2 + \dfrac{10}{3} x - \dfrac{\color{red}{16}}{3} = x^2 + \dfrac{10}{3} x - \dfrac{80}{\color{red}{15}}\,$.

Comment: well, $\frac {-10}6$ reduces to $\frac 13(-5)$ and $1060 = 4*265$ so $\sqrt{1060} = \sqrt{4*265} = 2\sqrt{265}$ so $\frac {\pm \sqrt{1060}}6$ reduces to $\frac 13(\pm \sqrt{265})$.  That you got 265 and the book got 73 is probably an arithmetic error.  (apparently on you book's end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution seems correct, indeed

$$x^{2} + \frac{10}{3}x -\frac{80}{3} = 0\iff3x^2+10x-80=0$$

$$ \frac{-10 \pm\sqrt{100-(4)(3)(-80)}}{6}=-\frac53\pm\frac{\sqrt{265}}{3}$$

Comment: so is my book wrong ?

Comment: Either your book is wrong, or you misread the question or made a typo here. This is the correct answer to this specific equation.

Comment: For given the quadratic equation this is the solution! Maybe it is symply a typo.

Comment: okay thank you for that!

Comment: @italy You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 0):

$$x=\frac{-10 \pm \sqrt{100-(4)(3)(-80)}}{6} =\frac{-2\times 5 \pm \sqrt{4\times25-(4)(3)(-80)}}{6} =\frac{1}{6}\left(-2\times 5 \pm 2\sqrt{25+240} \right) =\frac{2}{6}\left(-5 \pm \sqrt{265} \right)=\frac{1}{3}\left(-5 \pm \sqrt{265} \right)$$

Comment: That's consistant with the OP's answer.  The OP just didn't simplify it enough.  So that's not "wrong".  That's just not finished.

Comment: @Fleablood: He didn't include $-10$ with the fraction. Now I see it was a typo. I'll edit my answer. Thanks.